# adding scrolledwindow to textview via builder()

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I try to add scrolledwindow to textview via builder() and could not figure out how to do that

my code:

```
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):

        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_ALWAYS,gtk.POLICY_ALWAYS)

        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("test.glade")

        window = self.builder.get_object("window1")

        window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        window.set_default_size(200,200)
        window.set_title("Hello World in PyGTK")

        window.add(sw)
        textView1 = self.builder.get_object('textview1')

        textbuffer1 = textView1.get_buffer()
        start_iter1 = textbuffer1.get_start_iter()

        text=""
        for i in range(0, 100):
            text+=str("Hello World!")+"\n"
        textbuffer1.insert(start_iter1,  text)

        window.show_all()

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

This code throw an error:

> work3.py:24: GtkWarning: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkScrolledWindow to a GtkWindow, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkWindow can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkTextView
> window.add(sw)

test.glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="width_request">100</property>
    <property name="height_request">100</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTextView" id="textview1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You're mixing things up: you should add the textview to the scrolledwindow, not the other way around

Comment: Actually you are adding both, scrolled window and text view to the gtkwindow, that's not going to work. window -> scrolled -> textview is what you want to do. Also sto using pygtk (I believe) and start using pygobject